# Where to prevent field value change in custom component form record?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, component, development, mvc

Where is the best place in Joomla MVC (server-side) to forbid users from changing a value in a pre-existing form record? In JTable `check` / `bind`/ JModel `prepareTable`, or elsewhere?

For context, I have a form in my component with certain fields that shouldn't change after initial creation - though other fields are editable.

I can disable or simply not render the fields in the edit view of the item if it has an ID, but that won't stop a well-crafted POST, so I'd like to simply 'ignore' a series of values if the data array has an ID > 0 (and thus exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JTable` method `check` is design for

> Method to perform sanity checks on the JTable instance properties to ensure they are safe to store in the database.

`JTable` method `bind` is design for

> Method to bind an associative array or object to the JTable instance.

So both of them are not designed for what you are trying to do.

However `JModel` method `prepareTable` is designed for

> Prepare and sanitise the table data prior to saving.

So it's exactly what you need.

```
protected function prepareTable($table)
{
  // Row exists?
  if ((int)$table->id > 0) {
    // Ignore certain fields
    unset($table->ignoreFieldName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer - I had a feeling it was `prepareTable', but had a look at `bind` and saw we have that `ignore` parameter which won't bind certain values before save. Wondering if that's 'cleaner', as I'm already overriding `bind` for something else.

Comment: Yes, it is actually an option. And since your are already overriding `bind`, you can use that. You can pass `array` of fieldnames or `string` with space separated field names to ignore. It would work same way and would be cleaner in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the input - will leave this open for a day or 2 to see if anyone else has any thoughts, then mark as answered :)

Comment: Just working this up now - I've since found `prepareTable` works better here - `bind` is called on load AND save, which means any ignored fields won't appear in the edit layout (even as readonly) because they're never bound. Unset in `prepareTable` works great though!

Comment: Yeah. You are absolutely right. Then only `prepareTable` will be valid solution.